# Thermal Undershooting In SLM Simulation on Ansys Fluent

Tags: ansys, cfd

I am creating a SLM simulation of basalt on Ansys Fluent. I have enabled laminar viscosity, solidification and melting, and the energy equation. The heat flux is applied to the top wall through the thermal tab in the boundary conditions. I know based on experimental data that the temperatures are supposed to be around 1800 K, and I get this result when I have a time step of 0.2s and a mesh sizing of 0.00085m. However, I read the ansys thermal undershooting guide and I realized my mesh size is too large for the time step. When I adjust the mesh size appropriately to 0.0004m, the temperatures become very large, like 5000 - 6000K. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried starting from some kind of non-uniform steady state temperature distribution?

Comment: I solved the problem by displaying the cell values instead of the node values, it made the animation less smooth but gave better values.